# ReplyTo and Inout of camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want to know how ReplyTo works in Camel route and the route should be in XML. If possible please give one example.

I just go through on Internet, but I can't get the exact one.

Comment: I want to know how ReplyTo work in camel route  and the route should be in xml. If possible please give one example               Thanks